# Enabling login for a user on newly attached database SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a database that somebody else has built and I need to attach it on my SQL Server. The main user that owns schemas is named 'LSadmin'.

I want to use that same name for login to the server, and then have the rights for that login to access the database.

For some reason a login already exist LSadmin but it does not have any rights to access the attached database. When I want to Map the login to the database and give it datawritter and datareader for example, SQL Server shows that a user already exists.

When I try to delete the user to recreate it, then I can't because it owns schemas.

I found two ways to resolve this. One is to give the login a sysadmin rights, which of course is not desirable, and the other one is to move schemas ownership to another user, and then give database rights through mapping.

Is there any other solution that is not so "complicated"?

Comment: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1590/understanding-and-dealing-with-orphaned-users-in-a-sql-server-database/

Comment: @scsimon Thanks. That helped :-)

Comment: Glad to help. Good luck!